# Rendimiento lento al añadir un filtro OR más

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

Estoy experimentando un rendimiento lento en una consulta que contiene el siguiente tipo de filtro:

```
SELECT * FROM Tabla
WHERE ((A=2 AND B=2014 AND C=25 AND D=1) OR (E=2 AND F=2014 AND G=25 AND H=1))
OR ((A=2 AND B=2014 AND C=25 AND D=2) OR (E=2 AND F=2014 AND G=25 AND H=2))
OR ((A=2 AND B=2014 AND C=25 AND D=3) OR (E=2 AND F=2014 AND G=25 AND H=3))
```

Así hasta 24 líneas. La consulta es inmediata hasta que añado una condición más "OR" tal y como muestro:

`OR ((A=2 AND B=2014 AND C=25 AND D=25) OR (E=2 AND F=2014 AND G=25 AND H=25))`

En ese momento, el plan de ejecución cambia:

1. Pasa a paralelizar.
2. Deja de utilizar los dos índices creados con los campos de filtro (A,B,C,D por un lado y E,F,G,H por otro).
3. Pasa a hacer un index scan por la primary key de la única tabla de la consulta.

¿Por qué este cambio de comportamiento?, ¿Por qué al añadir un OR más deja de utilizar los índices del plan bueno y pasa a paralelizar?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Imposible que podamos responder eso sin saber la estructura de la tablas, los índices que contiene y al menos una idea de la distribución de datos que tiene

Answer (score 4):

Si solo cambia el último valor ¿Por qué repetir todos en las condiciones?
El problema es que estás complicando demasiado la consulta y eso genera confusiones en el optimizador. Cada variación va aumentando la capacidad de generar distintos planes de ejecución que el optimizador de consultas tiene que evaluar antes de seleccionar uno. Con tantas condiciones, termina siendo demasiado trabajo y se opta por una forma segura de regresar todas las filas necesarias.

Por lo general, paralelizar es bueno cuando se tienen muchas filas ya que aprovechamos la capacidad de tener procesadores de múltiples núcleos. Se cambia de los indices non-clustered al índice clustered porque es la forma segura de obtener los datos y no tiene que leer el índice non-clustered para luego buscar el resto de la información en el índice clustered puesto que estás regresando todas las columnas.

Una simplificación de la consulta quedaría de la siguiente manera, pero recuerda solo regresar las columnas necesarias y no todas:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tabla 
WHERE (A=2 AND B=2014 AND C=25 AND D BETWEEN 1 AND 25)
   OR (E=2 AND F=2014 AND G=25 AND H BETWEEN 1 AND 25)
```

EDIT:
Una forma alternativa, es crear una tabla que albergue los distintos valores que se pueden comparar. Así será más fácil para el optimizador manejarlo como un conjunto y no como múltiples valores escalares.

```
SELECT *
INTO #Filtro
FROM (VALUES(2, 2014, 25, 1),
            (2, 2014, 25, 2),
            (2, 2014, 25, 3),
            (2, 2014, 25, 4),
            (2, 2014, 25, 5))x(A,B,C,D);

SELECT * 
FROM Tabla t
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT * FROM #Filtro f WHERE t.A = f.A AND t.B = f.B AND t.C = f.C AND t.D = f.D)
   OR EXISTS( SELECT * FROM #Filtro f WHERE t.E = f.A AND t.F = f.B AND t.G = f.C AND t.H = f.D);
```

Comment: Buenos días, gracias por tu respuesta. El diseño del filtro es de los desarrolladores, ya preguntamos exactamente lo mismo pero nos confirmaron que podía cambiar cualquier valor. El ejemplo era simplemente eso, un ejemplo.

De todos modos, gracias por tu explicación de como funciona el optimizador, tiene bastante lógica como dices que se comporta y explicaría el motivo del cambio de plan.

Lo dicho, muchas gracias

Comment: Añadí una opción a la respuesta, espero que les pueda servir de algo. Si agregan índices al filtro puede funcionar mejor.